# Spring validation: How do I remove leading/trailing whitespace from an email before validation?

Tags: spring, validation, email

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I have a form mapped to a model that contains this field …

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
…

public class RegistrationForm extends PasswordForm
{

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
```

Then in my controller I have …

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView register(final Model model,
                             final HttpServletRequest request,
                             final HttpServletResponse response,
                             @Valid final RegistrationForm registrationForm,
                             final BindingResult result) throws IOException
```

However, if the email comes in with leading or trailing whitespace, the validation fails.  Is there a way to adjust my annotation or do something else simple that will allow my validation to pass and have the leading/trailing whitespace removed from the email address?  I’m looking for a server-side solution, so although I realize I could make Javascript do the dirty work, I’d like to do that on the server side.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `setEmail` in your `RegistrationForm` bean to:

```
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email.trim();
}
```

When `RegistrationForm` is being constructed, the value binded to `email` will be trimmed.